# Can Ambient Isotopies be Deformed to be Constant Away from a Compact Set?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, geometric-topology, plane-geometry, stability-theory

So I have this statement that I know (I guess I should say 99% sure until I actually see a proof):

> Let $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be compact and suppose $F$ is an ambient isotopy carrying $X$ to $Y$.  Then there is an ambient isotopy $F'$ carrying $X$ to $Y$ such that $F'$ is constant in a neighborhood of $\infty$.

In other words, if two compact spaces are ambient-isotopic, then you don't need to radically deform the entire plane just to get one to the other.  I think it's true for general $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the same argument I'll outline below.

I am having trouble finding a reference for this or proving rigorously that it's true.  Can anyone help?

I'm trying to prove it using the [Annulus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem).  My idea for the proof goes as follows.  Let $J_1$ be a circle large enough that the trace of $X$ and $Y$ under $F$ are contained in the *inside* (bounded complementary region, as opposed to *outside*) of $J_1$, and let $J_2$ be a circle such that the trace of $J_1$ under $F$ is contained in the inside of $J_2$.  I want to make it so $F'$ is constant on $J_2$ and its outside, and agrees with $F$ on $J_1$ and its inside.

So basically $F'$ should slide $J_1$ around inside $J_2$.  Let $A_t$ denote the annulus between $F_t(J_1)$ and $J_2$.  Then $A_0$ is the annulus between $J_1$ and $J_2$ and is homeomorphic to a 'typical' smooth annulus, so has a decomposition into 'transverse arcs'.  I want to drag the endpoints of these transverse arcs along $J_1$ according to the action of $F$, and have them stay fixed along $J_2$.

Visually it SEEMS clear that this process gives a continuous extension (it will be bijective by construction), since you can't get "infinite, large-scale winding" in "a compact amount of time," and that's "the only thing that can go wrong."  But that's a ton of handwaving.

Please help!

Comment: I suggest you do it in the smooth category; then the proof is quite simple: You multiply the  tangent vector field of your initial isotopy by a suitable compactly supported function.

Comment: Ah, so an averaging process?  How do you get that it's bijective still, especially after the smooth approximation?  That's the problem I'm having trouble seeing even in the smooth category; if I can understand it there (or PL) then I can probably get it for the topological case.  Basically this question is asking for a continuous selection of annular prime ends, but I can't find that formulation of the question either.  It's just assumed every time I see the topic broached XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do this in the smooth category. Let $F_t(z)$ denote a smooth isotopy, $t\in [0,1]$, $z\in {\mathbb R}^2$; let $K$ denote
$$
\{F_t(z): z\in X, t\in [0,1]\},
$$
a compact in the plane. ($F_0=id$, $F_1(X)=Y$.)

Let $B(0,R)$ denote a ball containing $K$.
Define the tangent vector field $Z(z,t)=\frac{d}{dt}F_t(z)$ of the flow. Let $\eta(z)$ be a (smooth) cut-off function, which is identically $1$ on $B(0,R)$ and identically $0$ on a  ${\mathbb R}^2\setminus B(0,2R)$. Now, define a new vector field $W(z,t)= \eta(z) Z(z,t)$. Since it is identically zero outside of $B(0,2R)$, this vector field defines a flow $G_t(z), t\in [0,1]$ which is constant outside of $B(0,2R)$. By the uniqueness theorem, $G_t(z)=F_t(z)$ for all $z\in B(0,R)$, in particular, all $z\in X$. Hence, $G_t$ is an isotopy taking $X$ to $Y$, which is the identity  outside of $B(0,2R)$.

I am sure one can also find an isotopy in the topological category, but that would take more work and I am not sure about the motivation.

Comment: Thanks, nice!  Your $\eta$ is sort of like shifting the problem to a hyperbolic metric outside of $B(0,R)$, I will try this trick.  Basically I need to force that as $x$ escapes to infinity it doesn't wind around $K$ to get a by-hand prime end extension, which will prove it.  I think the method is easy, some sort of increasingly fine twists on larger and larger annuli.